# A quick chanllenge: height and weight probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, information-theory, parameter-estimation

The average height and weight of a group of people is 175cm and 70kg; Find the upper bound of the portion of the people who are over 200cm and over 100kg.

I thought about Markov inequality, but I think height and weight are related? So P(H>200, W?100) can not be decomposed as P(H>200)P(W>100).

Get stuck. Anyone has any idea? Thanks!.

EDIT: This problem asks for a upper bound, so a reasonable tight upper bound is expected I suppose.

Comment: Hm. It looks like some knowledge of human physiology is required. Can there be people who weigh 0.1 kg? 1 kg? 10kg?

Comment: I think the answer yes, but not likely give the information provided in the questions. As soon as you know mean, then large law number theorem will limit the portion of unlikely events. I think this is described, as one of many ways, as Markov inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the problem as stated, I think the only way to bound it is as follows:  The most that can be over $200$ cm tall is $\frac 78$, which assumes those people are  exactly $200$ cm and the rest are $0$ cm tall.  The most that can be over $100$ kg is $\frac 7{10}$, which assumes everybody is either $100$ kg or $0$ kg.  The upper bound on the number of people who are both is the lower of these-$\frac 7{10}$  That leaves us $\frac 7{40}$ who are $0$ cm and $100$ kg?!?!.

Comment: I would have thought the fraction of people with infinite density would be a bit less than $7/40$...